# Closing jquery based menu when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I have integrated this menu in my website :

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/979/simple-google-style-Dropdown-menu-with-jQuery

I want the menu dropdown to be closed when clicked outside ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to document click event using `.one` on menu opening:

```
$(document).one("click", function() {
  $('#mymenu').hide();
});
```

On the clicking inside the menu terminate the event bubling.

Comment: Didn't know something like .one exist in jQuery before